# aws s3 upload upload only 128 kb

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, sftp

I need to upload a File from a SFTP to a S3 Bucket.
I'm using aws-sdk, defining a bucket S3 and then upload a Stream.
The problem is the file on the bucket is only 128 KB of the starting 8 MB.

Am i missing something?

I think the problem is that the upload method doesn't pass through the whole stream and stops at the first "step" of 128 KB.
Maybe some "await" put wrong?

```
export const saveFileToS3 = (stream: any, filePath : string) => {
    return new Promise<string>(async (resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
        try {
            const fileName = filePath.split('/')[3];
            const s3 = new AWS.S3({
                endpoint: 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
                signatureVersion: 'v4',
                accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              });
            let params = {
                Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME, 
                Key: process.env.S3_PATH + fileName, 
                Body: stream
            };
            var options = {
                partSize: 1500 * 1024 * 1024,
                queueSize: 100
            };
            await s3.upload(params, options, function(s3Err, data) {
                if (s3Err) throw s3Err
                console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
            });
            resolve(params);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

```
export const getFileFromFtp = (filePath: string, ftpConf: Appp.FTPConf) => {
    return new Promise<Stream>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        logger.info(`getFileFromFtp - file path: ${filePath}`);
        let client: SFTP;
        try {
            client = new SFTP();
            const msg = await client.connect(ftpConf); 
            logger.info(`ftp client connected to ${ftpConf.host}`, msg);
            const stream: Stream = await client.get(filePath);
            client.end();
            resolve(stream);
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error("error: " + error.message);
            client && client.end();
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

I expect the s3.upload to upload all the stream.